# Are the characters based on real people?

Tags: subete-ga-f-ni-naru

The art for *Subete Ga F Ni Naru* is much more "realistic" that most of the anime that's been coming out lately. It seems to me that each character is unique enough that they could be based on real life "models".
Is there any **documentation or word from the creators** if this is the case and if it is, who the original models were?

EDIT: in answer to the request to define reality: as you can see below, the art does not rely on different hair colors or hair styles to differentiate the characters. Each character has distinct facial features that reflect reality rather than an moefied idealized anime world.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The series was originally a mystery novel that subsequently was adopted to other media such as visual novels a d a live action series. It would help if you elaborated on what is so realistic about it.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ done...

Comment: Compare e.g. Gangsta, Arslan Senki (sort of), Parasyte, and Psycho-Pass  - other recent shows that also use fairly realistic character designs. I see no reason to suspect that the characters in Subete ga F ni Naru are based on real-life models; far more likely is that the character designer is just quite competent.

Comment: @senshin These portraits could easily be caricatures of real people and brings out a lot of character. The works you listed above feature characters that are much more generic. Regarding the competency of the character designer, I totally agree that the person is very competent. It reminds me of the character designer for Aladdin, who based princess Jasmine on a relative and young visitor to the studio.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this is mostly due to the chara-designer's style, Inio Asano. He doesn't take his designs from real people (or at least he doesn't say so), yet his works all have this realistic and very diverse type of people.

As opposed to many anime chara-designers, he's not an animator, but a mangaka, with a very detailed, realistic style, as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

He drew the original chara-designs and character sheets that were used by the animators at A1-Pictures for The Perfect Insider, and that's probably that style you noticed. If you're curious, his works are critically acclaimed (and not only for the crazy art), with mangas like *Solanin* or *Good Night Punpun*.

Even though, you can clearly see how his raw style evolved to a more simple, and "round" style when it wad adapted, but it still keeps this realistic aspect.

Hope it answered your questions, at least partially. Unfortunately, I couldn't find word from Asano on these specific designs.

Comment: deserves upvotes anyway

Comment: I just noticed the original question was *very* old. Woops. Well, I hope somebody will find this helpful some day anyway!

Comment: what's wrong with it being old?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you were the one who originally asked this. Well, I just though you might have found out the answer by yourself since December :)